# Latest version to support MySQL 5.1.69 ib* files

Tags: mysql, recovery, mysql-5.1

Would like to recover InnoDB data from a crashed server. The last backup indicated it was running MySQL server 5.1.69. When doing a recovery, the log files show that the current MySQL won't support `ib*` files from this far back.

I tried installing 5.1.69 from archives and compiling from sources, but no-go, rabbit hole of problems.

Does anyone know the latest version of MySQL to support 5.1.69 `ib*` files? Will try that as a last resort. If it doesn't work, will go with the latest backup and some auxiliary data to try to reconstruct as much as possible.

Comment: have you tried a docker file like https://hub.docker.com/r/vsamov/mysql-5.1.73

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to load it with 5.5. As a general rule, next version up should always work. You should be able to run mysqldump from there, or run mysql_upgrade to keep it as is for 5.5. Then if you want to upgrade from there, you have to go up to 5.6 and run mysql_upgrade again. Repeat for 5.7 and 8.0 depending on how far you need to upgrade.